# Failed to unmount /mnt/secure/staging

Tags: android, unmount

android  Unable to access files in SD card  ####Android无法访问SD卡中的文件

I am working on application where it create text files in the SD card.

I have a receiver which will execute logic to create files in SD card from that point I will keep on store some data into that .

So far it is working properly , but suddenly I stopped working.

I checked logcat output , I found some logs related to SD card mounting.

But do not have an idea to how to resolve this issue.

below are the log statements:

```
     1.464 W/Vold    ( 2357): Failed to unmount /mnt/secure/staging (Device or resource busy, retries 3, action 0)
     08-23 07:26:31.783 E/ProcessKiller( 2357): Process logcat (3344) has open file /mnt/secure/staging/abc1.txt
     08-23 07:26:31.783 E/ProcessKiller( 2357): Process logcat (3345) has open file /mnt/secure/staging/abc2.txt
     08-23 07:26:32.845 W/Vold    ( 2357): Failed to unmount /mnt/secure/staging (Device or resource busy, retries 2, action 1)
     08-23 07:26:33.173 E/ProcessKiller( 2357): Process logcat (3344) has open file /mnt/secure/staging/abc1.txt
```

I have added permission `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just because you're use multiple thread to access file. So, try to use synchronized in your open file function.

```
synchronized void openFile(String filePath) {
        // Code to open file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

before writing the text file into SD-card you must always check the media state

```
if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equalsIgnoreCase(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
{
    // read or write file logic here //
}
```